# Appium in Selendroid mode ( Android SDK API < 17 ) activity never started error

Tags: android, junit, appium, selendroid

I am trying to run my **Appium** test for **Android 2.4** device in **Selendroid** mode, I defined starter activity, everything is fine but it is giving me **Activity never started** error.

*These are my capabilities:*

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Selendroid");                  
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.***.***.***.SplashActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.***.***.***.SplashActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage","com.***.***.***");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

I checked couple posts from Google Groups, they were recommending to add `appWaitActivity` and `appWaitPackage` to capabilities. I tried it but it didn't change the result.

*This is the error I am getting:*

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
A new session could not be created. (Original error: com.***.***.***/com.***.***.***.SplashActivity never started. Current: undefined/undefined) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

***EDIT***

I tracked down  the issue and found out that **Appium** is using `dumpsys window` to get current activity. I ran this command in command line and on a **Android 2.3** device it returned nothing for mCurrentFocus. It returns current activity in other versions but it is empty for **2.3.**

Any idea?

Comment: I am also facing the same error. (Original error: com.***.***.***/.***Activity never started. Current: undefined/undefined)'. But I am testing in 2.3.3 and I do get my activity as output for mCurrentFocus with "dumpsys window windows" :|

Comment: Checked the source adb.js in appium and it used mFocusedApp to get the current activity and not mCurrentFocus. When I try dumpsys window windows, I do get mFocusedApp !! But couldnt get the issue in adb.js :/